# Using a swap method within a Positional Linked List class without creating new nodes.

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

wise ones. I am having difficulties implementing a swap method within a Positional Linked List class. The swap method will take input of two positions, "p" and "q" that will swap the positions and re-link the existing nodes. Any help is appreciated. 
This is what I have so far:

```
def swap(self, p, q):  # Problem 7.34
    valid_position = self._validate(p)
    valid_position2 = self._validate(q)
    element_p = valid_position._element
    element_q = valid_position2._element
    position_next = valid_position._next
    position_prev = valid_position._prev
    valid_position._next = valid_position2._next
    valid_position._prev = valid_position2._prev
    valid_position2._next = position_next
    valid_position2._prev = position_prev
    valid_position._element = element_q
    valid_position2._element = element_p
```

and it works for some cases but not all. I've been thinking about the header and trailer nodes and the various conditions that this applies to but am having lots of trouble.

This is the class Positional Linked List which inherits from a Doubly Linked List.

```
# Abstract Data Type : Positional List
# A positional list PL supports

# len(PL)
# PL.is_empty()

# Accessor Methods (getters)
# iter(PL) : Return a forward iterator (uses yield)
# PL.first(), PL.last() : Return position of first (last) element, or None
# if empty
# PL.before(p), PL.after(p) : Return the position immediately before (after) p,
# or None if p is first (last)


# Mutators Methods (setters)
# PL.add_first(e), PL.add_last(e) : Insert new element e in front (back) and return position
# PL.add_before(p, e), PL.add_after(p, e) : Insert new element e just before (after) p, return
# position
# PL.delete(p) : Remove and return element at position p. Also invalidates position p.
# PL.replace(p, e) : Replace and return element replaced at position p.

from DoublyLinkedList import _DoublyLinkedList as dlb

class PositionalList(dlb):
    # ------ nested Position class ---------------
    class Position:

        def __init__(self, container, node):
            self._container = container    # reference to linked list that 
            contains
                                           # node at this position
            self._node = node              # reference to node pointed to by 
        # this position

        def element(self):
            return self._node._element

        def __eq__(self, other):
            """Return True if other is a Position representing teh same 
            location as self."""
            return type(other) is type(self) and other._node is self._node

        def __ne__(self, other):           # !=
            return not (self == other)

    # --------------- private position Validation method
    # possible errors: p is not a Position, p is not in the current list, p 
    # is no longer valid
    # purpose of method: return the node pointed to by p if p is a valid 
    # position
    # self in this scope refers to an instance of a doubly linked list

    def _validate(self, p):
        """Return position's node, or raise an exception."""
        if not isinstance(p, self.Position):
            raise TypeError("p must be of type Position.")
        # if the list that contains p is not in the current list raise 
        # ValueError
        if p._container is not self:
            raise ValueError("p does not belong to this container.")
        if p._node._next is None:    # means underlying node has been 
        invalidated
            raise ValueError("p is no longer valid.")
        return p._node

    # --------------- private method to create a position
    def _make_position(self, node):
        """Return Poisition instance for a given node, None if node is a 
        sentinel."""
        if node is self.header or node is self.trailer:
            return None
        else:
            return self.Position(self, node)

    # ----------------- accessor methods -------------------------
    def first(self):
        return self._make_position(self.header._next)

    def last(self):
        return self._make_position(self.trailer._prev)

    def before(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._prev)

    def after(self, p):
        node = self._validate(p)
        return self._make_position(node._next)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Forward iterator of list elements."""
        # Allows the use of next()
        # Allows embedding into for loops
        pointer = self.first()
        while pointer is not None:
            yield pointer.element()  #return element stored at this position
            pointer = self.after(pointer)  # moves the pointer "forward"

    def __reversed__(self): # Problem 7.15
        """Backward iterator of list elements."""
        pointer = self.last()
        while pointer is not None:
            yield pointer.element()
            pointer = self.before(pointer)


    def find(self, e):  # Problem 7.13
        pointer = self.first()
        while e != pointer.element():
            if e == pointer.element():
                return pointer.element()
            pointer = pointer.after(pointer)

    # ---------------  mutator methods
    # override the _insert_between() from parent _DoublyLinkedList class
    # to allow returning a position rather than a node
    def _insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        node = super().insert_between(e, predecessor, successor)
        return self._make_position(node)

    def add_first(self, e):
        """Insert new element e in front and return a position."""
        return self._insert_between(e, self.header, self.header._next)

    def add_last(self, e):
        return self._insert_between(e, self.trailer._prev, self.trailer)

    def add_before(self, p, e):
        valid_position = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, valid_position._prev, valid_position)

    def add_after(self, p, e):
        valid_position = self._validate(p)
        return self._insert_between(e, valid_position, valid_position._next)

    def delete(self, p):
        """Remove and return element at position p. Invalidate position 
        p."""
        valid_position = self._validate(p)
        #p._container = None
        return self.delete_node(valid_position)

    def replace(self, p, e):
        """Replace and return element at position p."""
        valid_position = self._validate(p)
        element_to_return = valid_position._element
        valid_position._element = e
        return element_to_return

    def swap(self, p, q):  # Problem 7.34
        valid_position = self._validate(p)
        valid_position2 = self._validate(q)
        element_p = valid_position._element
        element_q = valid_position2._element
        position_next = valid_position._next
        position_prev = valid_position._prev
        valid_position._next = valid_position2._next
        valid_position._prev = valid_position2._prev
        valid_position2._next = position_next
        valid_position2._prev = position_prev
        valid_position._element = element_q
        valid_position2._element = element_p
```

This is the Doubly Linked List class:

```
# Abstract Data Type: Doubly Linked List
# A doubly linked list dll supports
# dll.is_empty()
# len(dll)
# dll.insert_between(e, predecessor, successor)
# dll.delete_node(a_node): should not delete the header and trailer nodes

# We will implement this class as an abstract class
# Meaning it is meant to be inherited by other data structures rather than
# instantiated directly



class _DoublyLinkedList(object):
    class _Node:
        # nested _Node class------------------------------------------------
        __slots__ = '_element', '_prev', '_next'

        def __init__(self, element, previous, next_):  # next is a reserved 
            # word, hence underscore
            self._element = element
            self._prev = previous
            self._next = next_

    class Empty(Exception):
        pass
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self.trailer = self._Node(None, None, None)
        self.header._next = self.trailer
        self.trailer._prev = self.header
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    def insert_between(self, e, predecessor, successor):
        new_node = self._Node(e, predecessor, successor)
        predecessor._next = new_node
        successor._prev = new_node
        self.size += 1
        return new_node

    def delete_node(self, a_node):
        """Should not delete sentinels."""
        # Error management POTENTIAL EXAM QUESTION so that it doesn't delete 
        # sentinels
        # if a_node == self.header or a_node == self.trailer:
        #     return Err

        prev_ = a_node._prev
        next_ = a_node._next
        prev_._next = next_
        next_._prev = prev_
        temp = a_node._element
        a_node._prev = a_node._next = None
        self.size -= 1
        return temp

    def middle(self):
        n = self.header._next
        m = self.trailer._prev
        if n == self.trailer:
            return None
        while n != m:
            n = n._next
            m = m._next
        return m

    def printLinkedList(self):
        node = self.header
        while node is not None:
            print(node._next)
            node = node._next

    def reverse(self):
        current = self.header

        while current is not None:
            temp = current._prev
            current._prev = current._next
            current._next = temp
            current = current.prev

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pl = PositionalList()

    # Add 2, 3, 4, 1
    p2 = pl.add_first(2)
    p3 = pl.add_after(p2, 3)
    p4 = pl.add_after(p3, 4)
    p1 = pl.add_after(p4, 1)

    pl.find(4)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest thing be to just swap the _element values? But given that you do want to swap the whole nodes, think about how many next and prev pointers you need to change. Draw it on paper.